Digital Circus Style Facial Rigging?
https://youtu.be/ZZh5Ny-fTjU?t=7
The video shows a 2D facial rig that appears to be controlled by 3D elements. It looks like the final result is rendered separately and then applied to the character. I might be mistaken, but I thought you all could help me figure out how this works so I can learn the techniques behind it.
It doesn’t seem to use separate images on a trim sheet; instead, it’s done "live" in real-time.
How can this be achieved in Blender alone? Are there any tutorials or resources that explain this method?

As written on the bottom of the YouTube video, the animation is performed on a proxy character, which is flat and composed by layers of 2D planes in a 3D world, deformed by bones, shape keys and lattices.
Once the animation is done, it gets rendered as a Black and white mask Image Sequence, that is then used to drive the colors of the final texture of the 3D model.
I tried a simple version of it and it works fine.
Brilliant Rig and workflow, anyway.


@Starius Which kind of details do you need? What do you already understand? It's difficult to offer a complete rigging course on a single answer ...

sorry for late reply man. I’d like a lil more detailed guidance on how to render the black-and-white mask sequence and correctly apply it as a texture driver for the final 3D model in Blender
